# Having return value for function based on input

Tags: typescript

I am writing a function that takes an object and transforms it to another object. The shape of the output object depends entirely on the shape of the input object. I would like to get typings of the output object, when invoking it with a specific input, but TS is not narrowing the output type for me. Does somebody know what the issue is here?

```
interface Atype {
  hello: true
}

interface Btype {
  world: false
}

interface Ctype {
  test: 10
}

interface Dtype {
  other: 11
}

type MAP = {
  hello: Ctype,
  world: Dtype
}

const doSmth = <T extends 'hello' | 'world'>(val: T): MAP[T] => {
  return val === 'hello' ? { test: 10} : { other: 11}
} // Type '{ test: 10; }' is not assignable to type 'Ctype & Dtype'.

const val1 = doSmth('hello') // val1 is correctly typed as Ctype
```

Comment: Should probably be `type MAP = Ctype | Dtype`

Comment: Without [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) this is not directly possible; you can work around it by refactoring to use generic indexing as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m0VVGw). See the linked questions and answers for more information